# Using the Action Chains with Firefox rightclick is happening but action is not taking place

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

With Firefox By using `ActionChains` giving the `right click` on the `map`, it should open the menu. but the problem is right-clicked is happening but the menu isn't opening. using `gecko driver version 0.30.0` and `Firefox 98.0`

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element_with_offset(element, x, y).context_click().perform()
```

with Chrome it is working fine.

Any views on this is it a gecko driver or Firefox issue?

Thank you

Comment: try this `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element_with_offset(element, x, y).pause(5).context_click().perform()`

Comment: yeah, I tried it isn't working. Thank you

Comment: shouldn't need the moveto stuff... try with just ActionChains(driver).context_click(element).build().perform()